# Mathematica 12.0 and BibTeX reference problem (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, citation-management

I have problems getting the Citation Management in Mathematica 12.0 to work. It does not work with either EndNote or BibTeX. To do a minimal example, I have the following BibTeX file (libra.bib) having only one reference:

@Misc{elliptic,
author =   {Wolfram, Stephen},
title =     {Solving the Quintic with {M}athematica},
howpublished = {http://library.wolfram.com/examples/quintic/},
year =     1999
}

When trying to Add Citation (using BibTex file) I get this error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on my system (Windows 10, Mathematica 12.1) as well - since the issue appears to be inside the front-end function ``FEPrivate`CurrentCitations`` (which returns `$Failed` for some reason), there's not much to debug - I'd suggest you contact support for help

Comment: Still an issue in V 13.0 on Windows 11 Pro. Citation management broken.